# How to get data from authenticated aws apigateway api method/url in java code

Tags: amazon-web-services, httpurlconnection, aws-api-gateway

I need to get data from an ApiGateway api method. My API is deployed and url is like /greetings. "greetings" is my resource name in which **I have a GET method with Authentication set to aws_iam.**

The method returns a json response which i want to simply fetch and return. Before authenticating below code was enough to get the response:

```
String url = "XXXX/greetings"; // xxxx is replaced by api url
URL obj = new URL(url);
con.setRequestMethod("GET");

//add request header
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}

in.close();

//print response
```

Note: I understand that I have to pass Authentication token with the request and **I am able to access the authenticated API url with Postman by using my AWS credentials.** **My query is how do I do this in Java?**

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the Java SDK on your API and use that to call your API. You can set the credentials on the client just like in Postman.

Here is a guide https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/api-gateway-java-sdk/ to generate and use Java SDK with API Gateway.

If for some reason you don't want to use the generated SDK, you can read up on [SigV4 signing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) and do that yourself or use a third party library like the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985931/how-to-generate-signature-in-aws-from-java).