# Generating AWS SQS signature from java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

I need to get message from AWS SQS with using Spring RestTemplate(binded a proxy), instead of aws sdk or spring cloud aws messaging,  because of some proxy problem of the company.

I need to generate a header string includes Authorization signature like that;

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/523535599964/MyAmazingQueue?Action=ReceiveMessage' \
--header 'X-Amz-Date: 20210623T133108Z' \
--header 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAXTZJHJFOEKI4UF45/20210623/us-east-2/sqs/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=2d926124ce07ca41c0f56af3bdddc81df19444df189b727ff02015f620cdfc6c'
```

This is generated by Postman.
[image]

I need to generate this signaturewith java and bind to HttpHeaders object.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", <generatedAuthString>);
headers.add("X-Amz-Date", <generatedAnother>);
.
.
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);

response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

---

I prefered using rest template, because using aws sdk while adding a proxy like below, doesnt work. Im getting timeout error when application is starting.

---

```
public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync() {
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration= new ClientConfiguration();
    clientConfiguration.setProxyHost(proxyurl);
    clientConfiguration.setProxyPort(proxyport);
    return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region)
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey)))
            .build();
}
```

I tried every item in this stackoverflow  question, but i got AccessDeniedException or SignatureDoesNotMatch exceptinon.

[How to generate Signature in AWS from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985931/how-to-generate-signature-in-aws-from-java)

Would be great if you could help.
Thank you.

Comment: Why can you not use the SQS Java (preferably the V2) API?

Comment: Hi @smac2020, Because it doesn't work with proxy. but it works while setting a proxy to restTemplate.

Comment: Can your proxy issue be solved via - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/http-configuration.html

Comment: I have used ClientConfiguration, described -here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/section-client-configuration.html,   How can i use it or how can bind a defined AwsCrtAsyncHttpClient  to my AmazonSQSAsync  ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved finally :)

```
AmazonSQSClientBuilder builder = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard();
AmazonSQS sqs = builder.withClientConfiguration(
        PredefinedClientConfigurations.defaultConfig()
                .withProxyHost("**")
                .withProxyPort(****).withProxyPassword("***").withProxyUsername("****"))
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
        .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
        .build();
```

I used aws sdk instated of spring cloud aws
I used PredefinedClientConfigurations instated of ClientConfiguration.
thanks all!