# Quarkus Rest client and AWS Signature authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, quarkus, aws-java-sdk, quarkus-rest-client

I want to plug a Quarkus Rest Client on an AWS REST API Gateway which requires authenticating requests using AWS Signature.

How to integrate [Quarkus Rest Client](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive) (`@RegisterRestClient`) with [AWS Signature v4 authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html)?

As far as I understand, it boils down to compute a signature using [AWS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985931/how-to-generate-signature-in-aws-from-java) and add some HTTP Headers to client requests.